# DocuSign API - Identity Verifications List Empty in Demo Environment

Tags: docusignapi

I'm wanting to test out [SMS Authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/phone-auth/) when sending an envelope using the DocuSign eSignature API. According to the docs I first need to get the list of Identity Verification workflows, but when I make a request to that [endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/identityverifications/list/) in the demo/Sandbox environment I'm getting an empty array:

```
{
"identityVerification" : []
}
```

I can send an envelope using the web app/interface and enable SMS Authentication so not sure why I can't get the list of Identity Verification workflows via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plesse reach out to customer support.
They can help you add the IDV festure or Phone/SMS authentication for your developer account.

Comment: Thanks - I asked them to add Phone/SMS Authentication to my developer account and was advised they had "enabled ID Verification on your demo account". When I send a request with SMS Identity authentication instead of getting the SMS send a code screen I get a "Let's Verify your identity" guide. When I downloaded the list of IdentityVerifications there was one record with "defaultName" : "DocuSign ID Verification" and "defaultDescription" : "The signer will need to identify themselves with a valid government ID." That doesn't look like the Phone/SMS one does it?

Comment: no, that's IDV. You need to ask them to enable SMS auth, which is not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks - they were able to add this the 2nd time around.